# Parse the required parameters from the JAR run command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I write a Java tool to parse server log with the `Spring boot`. Eventually, the app will be converted to a `JAR` file. When, I will run the command like,

```
java -cp "parser.jar" com.ef.Parser --startDate=2017-01-01.13:00:00 --duration=hourly --threshold=100
```

The tool will find any IPs that made more than 100 requests starting from 2017-01-01.13:00:00 to 2017-01-01.14:00:00 (one hour) and print them to console AND also load them to another MySQL table with comments on why it's blocked.

The app structure is provided,

[image]

The spring boot `Parser.java` file is like,

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ef"}, exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Parser implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Parser.class);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Let's imagine I'm in the folder of the `parser.jar` and I run the command provided earlier. In this scenario, how do I strip off the `startDate`, `duration` and the `threshold` parameters in the variables?

Obviously, I can write the method to parse the `startDate` or the `duration` from a `String`, but, I'm little confused in the scenario.

Comment: not sure what you mean, do you need to get the arguments passed down to main method?

Comment: Yes, that will also work to have the arguments in the main methods. If I can parse the values of the mentioned parameters from the command, I can do the rest work

Comment: check this mate: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html  check *Parsing the command line arguments* section